# Python - Plotting confidence error bars with Maxwell Distribution

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

i've never tried implementing error bars based off of confidence intervals. Being that this is what I want to do, i'm unsure how to proceed further.

I have this large data array that consists ~1000 elements. From plotting the histogram that has this data, it looks well enough like a Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution.

Lets say my data is called `x`, which I apply the fitting for it as

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

maxwell = stats.maxwell

## Scale Parameter
params = maxwell.fit(x, floc=0)
print params

## mean
mean = 2*params[1]*np.sqrt(2/np.pi)
print mean

## Variance
sig = (params[1])**(3*np.pi-8)/np.pi
print sig

>>> (0, 178.17597215151301)
>>> 284.327714571
>>> 512.637498406
```

To which when plotting it

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,7))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

xd = np.argsort(x)

ax.plot(x[xd], maxwell.pdf(x, *params)[xd])

ax.hist(x[xd], bins=75, histtype="stepfilled", linewidth=1.5, facecolor='none', alpha=0.55, edgecolor='black', 
    normed=True)
```

[image]

How on earth do you go about implanting confidence intervals with the curve fit?

I can use

```
conf = maxwell.interval(0.90,loc=mean,scale=sig)
>>> (588.40702793225228, 1717.3973740895271)
```

But I have no clue what do with this

Comment: I believe your `sig` might be off, it seems very large. If I understand correctly, `maxwell.interval` will give you a range in your `x` data (cf. your plot) where the random variable will fall with 90% chance. You won't get point-wise error bars from that. But even if you get actual confidence intervals for your fitted parameters: you'll only get estimates for the two (one) parameter(s) of the fitted model. I guess what you *could* do is look at these confidence intervals of the fitted parameters, and plot upper and lower curves for the density that you fit.

Comment: Then again I could be wrong, and I suspect that most of this question would be on topic on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). You should check.